# Getting connection refused error using openllm library of python

Tags: flask, nlp, localhost, python-3.8, large-language-model

I am trying to utilise [this](https://github.com/bentoml/OpenLLM) github repo, particularly the below python code:

`import openllm client = openllm.client.HTTPClient('http://localhost:3000') client.query('Explain to me the difference between "further" and "farther"')`

But this is throwing following error:[connection refuse error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbure.png)

How do I run the server for above code to work ?

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the ["Starting an LLM Server
" section](https://github.com/bentoml/OpenLLM#starting-an-llm-server) of the github project you linked to.

For instance, to start a server with the OPT model, you would do as follows:

```
openllm start opt
```

Once you do that, you can open http://localhost:3000 on a web browser to check if it's working and to experiment with the endpoints and sample input prompts.